# How to fix likewise-open after installing winbind?

Tags: linux, active-directory

I have a situation.
In a machine that used to log in an AD domain through likewise, I installed winbind. It erased the previous configuration files and rewrote them with its own data. Now I can't get it to work again.

Anyone has ever had this problem? Is there an "easy" way to fix the mess winbind did?

Comment: Likewise, winbind will interfere with likewise-open https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/likewise-open/+bug/986974

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem: you just need to run the likewise-open installer again. I did it and it fixed the problem caused. I found out that winbind effectively removed likewise from the machine.